# T480s Dolby speakers not best quality

Tags: ubuntu, audio, thinkpad, dolbydigital

I have a question about the speaker quality of the Lenovo T480. When I bought the laptop, it was advertised that the speakers are "Dolby Premium sound", but they are weak (not bad, but just not loud enough).

I have no idea how to check whether I have the right drivers/packages installed. How can I check/install packages for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

[image: My sound settings]

Comment: Computer audio hardware can’t output the same kind of sound you can get from a 300 watt receiver

Comment: Speakers are only as good as their inputs ...

Comment: "Dolby Premium Sound" is a license specification provided by Dolby and purchased, mostly for marketing reasons, by Lenovo. Like Beats on HP laptops and other branded audio specifications the average person may end up underwhelmed by what they hear. If you are hearing sound, you probably have the appropriate drivers. Though, visiting the OEM support website you can also likely find the latest drivers as well as documentation on their installation and use.

Comment: I've compared a T480s with a T470s and T480s is a lot worse! I would say the speakers are actually "bad" (or maybe I just had a faulty model). Most TP T models have awful sound, but T480s is a new low!